# GetX intent arg:I have two view A & B ,view A have controller A & B have controller B, when I intent arg from a to detail view it work, but b not work

Tags: flutter, dart

Screen A

```
return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Get.toNamed(
                                    Routes.storeDetail,
                                    arguments: item,
                                  );
                                },
                                child: CardStoreNearYouCell(
                                  width: size.width,
                                  height: size.height * 0.25,
                                  item: item,
                                ),
```

Screen B

```
InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                log("message: ${storeData.storeId}");
                                Get.toNamed(
                                  Routes.storeDetail,
                                  arguments: storeData,
                                );
                              },
                              child: CardStoreNearYouCell(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.8,
                                item: Item(
                                  discountType: storeData.discountType,
                                  name: storeData.name!,
                                  storeId: storeData.storeId!,
                                ),
                              ),
```

controller: this arg can get data from screen A only if I final when I try intent from screen b it shows:: message error like that [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'CategoryDetailItem' is not a subtype of type 'Item?'

```
void onInit() async {
 scrollController = ScrollController();
 scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
 if (arg is CategoryDetailItem) {
  store = arg;
  log("Information arg from store near you:: $store");
}
if (arg is Item) {
  log("Information arg from store near you: $arg");
  store = arg;
}

await fetStoreDetail();
configTabBar();
super.onInit();
```

}

Comment: try make it else if in arg is Item since the first one to be read is the above on args is item

Comment: Thank you brother Now I try your flow it working fine.

Comment: Could you tell me why you do not recommend using GetX.